# How to insert month and year for salary report

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, database-design

I'm trying to save employees' monthly salary report in the database using PHP and MySQL. So how can I add only month and year to store it into the database? So do I still need to include date? But including the date to the database will make no sense because the salary report will be based on the month, not date. Any suggestion?

Comment: In my opinion, its best to store date value in a date datatype column. There's so much you can do with just a date value. You might not need it now but who knows in the future. Just store the first date of the month should be fine. But it depends...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing this information as a `date` datatype. If you do not care about the day of the month, just the first of the month consistently.

The benefits of this approach are:

- data integrity: the database ensures that whatever you store is a valid date at the time when it is written; if you use another datatype, this will be much more complicated to do: how can you tell before hand than `2020-13` is not a valid date?
- efficiency: storing your data as `date`, you can take opportunity of MySQL date arithmetic features, and use date functions as you like (for example: adding 7 months to a given date is an easy thing when using the proper datatype, but is much more complicated with a custom value)

Answer (score 0):

> you can save the date in db and when you were fetching report you can
> use MONTH(),YEAR() function of mysql query for you condition else you
> have to create two columns in  table to store year and month seprately